# ubuntu-software crashes after opening

Tags: software-center, segmentation-fault

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and last night I had an update to the version. now when I'm trying to run the ubuntu-software\gnome-software and after it loads it writes "software catalog is being loaded" that load the main screen and crush (not 100% certain it's correlate to the update last night cause I haven't entered the software center in weeks)

I tried running

```
gdb ubuntu-software
```

and used

```
run
```

and I get this message

```
Starting program: /usr/bin/ubuntu-software 
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
[New Thread 0x7fffe7246700 (LWP 5986)]
[New Thread 0x7fffe6a45700 (LWP 5987)]
[New Thread 0x7fffe4b4c700 (LWP 5988)]
[New Thread 0x7fffcea52700 (LWP 5989)]
05:59:34:0280 Gs  enabled plugins: os-release, packagekit-refresh,systemd-updates, packagekit-upgrade, packagekit-proxy, fwupd, packagekit-refine-repos, packagekit, ubuntuone, desktop-categories, packagekit-offline, shell-extensions, packagekit-url-to-app, packagekit-local, appstream, steam, hardcoded-blacklist, ubuntu-reviews, generic-updates, desktop-menu-path, modalias, hardcoded-popular, rewrite-resource, hardcoded-featured, packagekit-refine, provenance, snap, packagekit-history, icons, provenance-license, key-colors, key-colors-metadata
05:59:34:0280 Gs  disabled plugins: dummy, dpkg, repos, epiphany, odrs
[New Thread 0x7fffcc829700 (LWP 5990)]
[New Thread 0x7fffc79f9700 (LWP 5996)]
05:59:34:0870 PK  internal error: failed, but no error code: cancelled-priority
[New Thread 0x7fffc71f8700 (LWP 6000)]
[New Thread 0x7fffc69f7700 (LWP 6001)]
[New Thread 0x7fffc61f6700 (LWP 6002)]
[New Thread 0x7fffc59f5700 (LWP 6003)]
[Thread 0x7fffc59f5700 (LWP 6003) exited]
[Thread 0x7fffc71f8700 (LWP 6000) exited]
[Thread 0x7fffc69f7700 (LWP 6001) exited]
[New Thread 0x7fffc69f7700 (LWP 6005)]
[New Thread 0x7fffc71f8700 (LWP 6006)]
[New Thread 0x7fffc59f5700 (LWP 6007)]
[New Thread 0x7fffc51f4700 (LWP 6008)]
05:59:34:0921 Gs  Only 0 apps for recent list, hiding

Thread 7 "pool" received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
[Switching to Thread 0x7fffc79f9700 (LWP 5996)]
0x00007ffff7428694 in g_date_time_to_unix ()
from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
```

I tried reinstalling the libglib and tried upgrading but nothing seems to work
if anyone have a solution I will be happy
thanks for those who help